# Is there a way to hack on The Gold Mine on a school chromebook?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I want to hack the game and give myself some iron bars, but I am on a school Chromebook and it doesn't have f12 or the inspect feature. Can anyone tell me how to hack it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is fundamentally "how do I access developer tools on a school chromebook", which is tangential to gaming

Comment: As an aside: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650294/how-can-i-inspect-element-on-a-chromebook-when-inspection-is-disabled, it is not (normally, unless you exploit the device in some way, up to and including opening it up and physically hacking in) possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chromebook specifically, you can trigger function keys by pressing the search key and the equivalent number key together. So pressing search and 1 will trigger F1. 0 is the equivalent of 10, for F10. For 11 and 12, use the keys to the right of 0, same as if you were proceeding on a number line.

Therefore, F12 should be triggerable by pressing search and +

The other way to open the browser dev tools (assuming that's what you're after) is ctrl+shift+J. This also works on non-chromebook PCs.

(Also this isn't "hacking" anything, but is likely considered cheating for javascript-based browser games.)

Comment: Many administrated chromebooks have inspect disabled. I would recommend using a javascript: url

Comment: I figured it was better to answer the question as-asked instead of trying to guess what the specific setup/restrictions were. The kids I tutor don't have inspect disabled on their school chromebooks.

Comment: "it doesn't have f12 **or** the inspect feature"

Comment: I have no idea what "the inspect feature" is. F12 is the dev tools, and makes sense because there are no function keys on chromebooks.

Comment: Maybe the admin hid the "inspect page" from the context menu? Idk.

Comment: I am pretty sure they mean the Inspect Element menu button that opens the dev tools. If this button is disabled, it's pretty safe to assume that the DevTools are not enabled.

Comment: Unless OP comes back and explains what exactly she meant, we're just speculating here. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same thing you use in the console normally, but prepend javascript:, so the result looks like (example): `javascript:aisdisidsidsidi.sdaiidis=daisdisisi`. Note that Google Chrome removes javascript: from pasted urls for security reasons, so you will have to type it while in the omnibar.

**Note**: You may have to put `;void 0` after if the JavaScript URL replaces your entire page with some text.